# How to use CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation with swift?

Tags: swift

I am developing  with  audioQueueService  
But stop in function "CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation" 
here is my code but always get nil for return.

```
var path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "123", ofType: "mp3")!

var xyz = UInt8(path.utf8CString[0])

let audioFileURL =  CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault,&xyz, path.characters.count, false)

print(audioFileURL)
```

I had try post path's point to func but not work?
can anyone help me?

Comment: That code makes no sense. Why don't you use `let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:...)`  ?

Comment: Yes you are right! I was addiction folllow the audioqueueServiceGuide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "123", withExtension: "mp3")!

        let audioFileURL = url as CFURL
```